# js recursion - not works

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have structure of folders and files as following:

```
var dir1 = {
    files:[],
    sub_dirs:{
        "yoyo" : {
            files:["koko"]
        }
   }
}
```

and i need to find all the paths of specific file name , i do it in recursion (look in jsfiidle) and i success to do it only if i have one sub directory as above example but if i have more than one it not works:

```
var dir2 = {
    files : ["bobo"], 
    sub_dirs : {
        "yoyo":{
            files:["koko"],
            sub_dirs:{
                "toto1":{
                    files:["bono"],
                    sub_dirs:{
                        "tomo1":{
                            files:["koko"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "soso":{
            files:["koko"],
            sub_dirs:{
                "toto2":{
                    files:["bono"],
                    sub_dirs:{
                        "tomo2":{
                            files:["koko"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

it prints only the paths in the first directory.
see http://jsfiddle.net/c3fzrx8c/
how can i fix it?

Comment: looks like your JSON in invalid . verify it [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I found two issue in your code.

I guess you know but i want to remind you, If you don't specify type means **VAR** for any variable it becomes GLOBAL variable or object.

So here:

Inside helper --

```
function helper(filename , dir , arrValidpathes , path){
        files = dir.files;
        subdirs = dir.sub_dirs;
}
```

those files and subdirs becomes global and you are updating them in each recursion.
I guess that makes sense to you.

Second issue.

Use for(var key in object) instead of while loop because you want to iterate object not array.

So if you use:

```
for(var directory in dir.sub_dirs){
  var tempPath  = path + "/" + directory;
  helper(filename , dir.sub_dirs[directory] , arrValidpathes , tempPath);
}
```

instead of your while loop it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. I modified sub_dirs so as to be arrays of objects.

```
var filename = "koko";

// ./koko
var dir = {
    files: ["koko"]
};


// ./yoyo/koko
var dir1 = {
    files: [],
    sub_dirs: [{
        "yoyo": {
            files: ["koko"]
        }
    }]
};


//./yoyo/koko/
// ./yoyo/toto/tomo/koko
// ./soso/koko
// ./soso/toto2/tomo2/koko
var dir2 = {
    files: ["bobo"],
    sub_dirs: [{
        "yoyo": {
            files: ["koko"],
            sub_dirs: [{
                "toto1": {
                    files: ["bono"],
                    sub_dirs: [{
                        "tomo1": {
                            files: ["koko"]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        },
        "soso": {
            files: ["koko"],
            sub_dirs: [{
                "toto2": {
                    files: ["bono"],
                    sub_dirs: [{
                        "tomo2": {
                            files: ["koko"]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
};

var arrValidpathes = [];
lookup(dir, filename);
lookup(dir1, filename);
lookup(dir2, filename);


function lookup(dir, filename) {
    helper(filename, dir, [], "./");
}


function helper(filename, myDir, arrValidpathes, path) {
    if (myDir == null || myDir == undefined) return;
    var files = myDir.files;
    var allsubdirs = myDir.sub_dirs;

    if (files != null && files != undefined && files.indexOf(filename) != -1) {
        console.log(path + "/" + filename);
    }

    if (allsubdirs == null || allsubdirs == undefined) {
        return;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < allsubdirs.length; i++) {
            var subdirs = allsubdirs[i];

            for (var item in subdirs) {
                path = path + "/" + item;
                helper(filename, subdirs[item], arrValidpathes, path)
            }
        }
    }

}
```